# LinkedIn API Without Authentication

Tags: api, oauth, linkedin-api, access-token, linkedin-jsapi

I'm making this web application for my company, which extracts basic data from LinkedIn and shows it to the user/employee. I want it to be a very user-friendly experience, hence don't want many login prompts, not even of linkedIn.
There is an itegrated authentication utility that can get the name credentials of the user without him having to fill it. 
So is there any way the application uses the firstName, lastName and companyName to search the employee on LinkedIn and display his/her basic data, without him/her having to authenticate using LinkedIn?
I read a bit about tokens, on the developer website, but I didn't understand how to use it?

Any answers/links/examples/hints would really help.

By the way, I'm using Javascript. Not XML, REST or PHP. Even though I wouldn't mind getting an answer in PHP either.

Thanks in advance!